# "it was every man and woman for themselves"

Tags: word-usage, singular-vs-plural, singular-they

> …it was every man and woman for themselves.

Or should it be 'for himself and herself'? or maybe just 'himself' referring to both?

Answer (score 1):

Several decades ago<sup>1</sup>, it would have been more common to not mention the female gender at all, even when meaning both men and women:

> …it was every man for himself.

This phrase is, in fact, still in use today, but mostly in situations where you can be sure only men are involved (such as with some sports, which can be gender segregated).  That said, these days, many people are becoming more and more uncomfortable with using male gendered language to refer to both men and women, and so efforts are made to include both genders in speech when both genders are (or could be) involved.

When including both men and women, we can't use either the masculine "himself" or the feminine "herself".  Fortunately, we do have a gender neutral pronoun<sup>2</sup> that can include both or either: "they/them".  Unfortunately, the grammatical form of this word is plural.  [Even though the singular "they" exists](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/grammar/singular-they), it is still *grammatically* plural.  As such, you can't say "themself"<sup>3</sup>, but have to say "themselves".

> …it was every man and woman for themselves.

This is correct.  We're still talking about each man and each woman separately, we're just using the "singular they". This is correct grammatically, idiomatically, and in fact, this phrase is very commonly used in many different circumstances.

Notes:

<sub>1. No later than the 1960s, [according to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they).</sub>

<sub>2. Sometimes also known as a gender agnostic pronoun.</sub>

<sub>3. Okay, the sources do say that you *can* say "themself", but that it is uncommon to do so.  I will add that it's so uncommon that I've *never* heard it before even though I'm a native speaker, and it sounds *really* wrong to me.  Official sources saying that "themself" is sometimes acceptable doesn't change how the word works in this example however, as the phrase using the non-plural form [is basically ***never*** used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22for+themselves%22%2C%22for+themself%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%22%20for%20themselves%20%22%3B%2Cc0) (according to google).</sub>

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.